# Mocking mongoose using Sinon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, sinon

Is it possible to mock mongoose methods that are used in files that are not spec files? I would like to be able to mock operations in way similiar to this example:

models/user.js:

```
userSchema.statics.SetUsername = function (userId, username, callback) {
        instance.findOneAndUpdate({ UserId: userId },
            { $set: { Name: username } },
            { new: true },
            function (error, doc) {
                if (error) {
                    logger.error(error);
                    callback({ error: error });
                } else {
                    callback(doc);
                }
            })
        }
```

spec/userSpec.js:

```
describe("User module", function () {
var User = require('../models/User');
var UserMock = sinon.mock(User);
UserMock
.expects('findOneAndUpdate').withArgs( {UserId: 9 },{ $set: { Name: 'Lol'}},{ new: true })
.yields(null, {UserId: 9, Username: 'Lol'});

describe("POST /setUsername", function () {
    it("returns status code 200", function (done) {
        request.post({
            url: setUsernameUrl,
            qs: { userId: '9', username: 'Lol' }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, `findOneAndUpdate` inside the `SetUsername` function doesn't get mocked up.

If that is generally a bad idea, could you propose another approach?

@EDIT:
I think I understand why this makes no sense. Now I am looking for a way of testing sole mongoose methods, by invoking them from the test, not by sending a request to the test server. The test would look like this:

```
it("returns document", function (done) {
            User.SetUsername(9, 'Lol', function (result) {
                expect(result).not.toBeNull();
                expect(result.UserId).toBe(9);
                expect(result.Username).toBe('Lol');
                done();
            })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, so I just forget to mock another method that uses database connection (which causes Error: Timeout. This answer applies to the edited version of the question.